# Why am I not able to Read SEGD Ver2.1?

Tags: python-3.x

The file is a binary file, an seismic acquisition one with the extension `SEG D Ver2.1`. I tried to read it with Python, I get the following error

```
File "/tmp/sessions/73b85d6eec85ca89/main.py", line 1
    f = open("C:\Users\VOLCOUR\Desktop\3D Tinhert_Rap_Final_ Mesa to Client\local_200121_031030500_dsd01.segd", "rb")
            ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```